# why there is a 2 in general purpose SSD AWS storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, solid-state-drive

what does a "2" refers in SSD gp2 AWS storage?
I am refering to General Purpose(GP) Solid State Disk(SSD) in AWS,but why a "2" in gp2.I understand EC2 stands for Elastic Cloud Compute, but in GP2 there are no two P's.

Comment: Its the second generation of General Purpose SSD, so no 2P's just generations.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a name. Don't get too hung-up on it.

Yes, while the numbers in EC2 and S3 are due to duplicated letters (Elastic Compute Cloud, Simple Storage Service), the EBS volume types are generational names, like the EC2 instance types (eg t1, m4, c5).

The EBS volumes types are:

- General Purpose SSD (`gp2`)
- Provisioned IOPS SSD (`io1`)
- Throughput Optimized HDD (`st1`)
- Cold HDD (`sc1`)
- Magnetic (`standard`)